# How to handle API responses globally in ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, refactoring

I have a couple of controller methods that call APIs and I handle the responses using a switch statement like the one below.

Question:

1. Is there a way to refactor my code to handle the responses from one place instead of having pretty much the same switch statement in every request?
   NOTE: I have a BearerTokenHandler class file. Could I handle the responses there?

```
var apiResponse = _httpClient.PostAsync()

switch (apiResponse.StatusCode)
{
  case HttpStatusCode.OK:
    //Parse response
  break:

  case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
    //Parse response
  break:

  case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
    //Parse response
  break

  case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
    return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");

  default:
    // ViewData["Error"]
  break:
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I can't write a way to create a separate 'function' or 'class' to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you can refactor your code. Here I just point out the two most common ways.

1. Make an `HttpClient` service and put all the work (POST, GET) relate to `HttpClient` there
2. Have a `BaseController` and generic methods. Then inherit all common works there.

It's better to combine two ways, which means always having a `BaseController` and made some services to handle related things.

Here is the example code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // Put all the cross cutting-concern things here
    // Like: Object Mapper, Logger, Cache Manager, etc...
    // So that you can use them without re-initialize
}
```

Make the interface `IHttpClientService` and its implementation `HttpClientService`. If you're using the ASP.NET Core then use its default Dependency Injection, otherwise if you using the old ASP.NET MVC, read this [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

```
public interface IHttpClientService
{
    Task<IActionResult> PostAsync();
}

public class HttpClientService : IHttpClientService
{
    public async Task<object> PostAsync()
    {
        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var apiResponse = _httpClient.PostAsync();

        switch (apiResponse.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                //Parse response
                break;

            case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                //Parse response
                break;

            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                //Parse response
                break;

            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");

            default:
                // ViewData["Error"]
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can implement your controller

```
public class YourController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IHttpClientService _httpClientService;

    public YourController(IHttpClientService httpClientService)
    {
        _httpClientService = httpClientService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> YourMethod()
    {
        var result = await _httpClientService.PostAsync();
        // You can use the logger from the BaseController to do something here
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If the apiResponse is 401, how can return a "Indicator" to MyController to redirect to a specific view such as AccessDenied? I assume we cannot use ViewData or RedirectToAction() from the HttpClientService.

Comment: You can wrap your controller logic in a `try {...} catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex) { // Redirect to action here} catch(Exception ex) {// Handle general/other exceptions}`. Then in the service when you encounter an `401` response, just throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` there

Answer (score 0):

You could have a BaseContoller class that accepts a generic model to post and then each of your post methods can just call this instead.